# How to disable Bit Torrent Client

Tags: security, bittorrent

There is a lot of traffic generated by my Transmission Bit Torrent client which I don't use at all. I see that this application comes pre installed in Ubuntu 12.04.

So, is there a way through which I can stop this traffic generated un necessarily by this torrent client or for better how can I uninstall this application. Thanks.

**Edit 1.**

Output of ps aux piped with transmission

```
ps aux | grep transmission

root      9276  0.0  0.0  13584   912 pts/2    S+   16:22   0:00 grep --color=auto transmission
```

Comment: I don't understand how it's generating network traffic if you aren't using it.

Comment: Ya. I have seen torrent traffic being generated in my router. Ya its not that much but for the sake of security of the network I want to disable it. Also its of no use.

Comment: Is there another computer on your network that could be using a bittorrent client and generating this traffic? per what you're showing, you're not really running transmission at all.

Comment: No i don't believe anyone is using it because the data transmission is not so much that I can suspect a download or something I believe some background process is doing it and in almost all the systems.

Comment: Unless you open it, the program does not run, and so does not generate any traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to know the cause of it. The p2p file sharing data was due to Skype service. I studies the different links and all of them were either pointing towards Skype or Microsoft Corporation. After a bit of googling about Skype. I got to know of the following facts.

**Skype is a hybrid peer-to-peer and client–server system. It makes use of background processing on computers running Skype software, and this is reflected in Skype's original proposed name of Sky Peer-to-Peer.
Some network administrators have banned Skype on corporate, government, home and education networks, citing reasons such as inappropriate usage of resources, excessive bandwidth usage, and security concerns.**

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skype)

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think transmission should start with Ubuntu, but transmission-daemon does.

```
sudo apt-get remove transmission-gtk
```

should remove it.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't generate traffic unless you use it. It doesn't run unless you run it. If it is responsible for any bandwidth, you or somebody else on the computer is using it to download or upload torrents.

So the simplest answer: stop using it.

If you're seeing network traffic at router level, check to see if it's actually transmission that's responsible. `ps aux | grep transmission` will show you any processes with transmission in their name.

Edit: you can remove it with a simple `sudo apt-get remove transmission{,-gtk}` and that won't hurt Ubuntu. `ubuntu-desktop` just "recommends" `transmission-gtk` so it won't tank the system per my last version.

Comment: `ps aux |grep [t]ransmission` will not show the `grep` command itself which may make it clearer that transmission is indeed not running.